# dynamically setting ng-model name when using ng-repeat (or how to use ng-repeat item value as ng-model name)

Tags: angularjs

I have a some fields that gets dynamically generated based on ng-repeat. However I need to set the ng-model name for these field dynamically and this should be either based on $index from ng-repeat or it should have the ng-repeat item value as name for ng-model.

Below is my code

```
 <div class="panel-body"
                        data-ng-controller="XModelController as xmdlCtrl">

 ................

 ................

 <th data-ng-repeat="item in ['xmdlCtrl.rsptYrs.year1Date', 'xmdlCtrl.rsptYrs.year2Date', 'xmdlCtrl.rsptYrs.year3Date', 'xmdlCtrl.rsptYrs.year4Date', 'xmdlCtrl.rsptYrs.year5Date', 'xmdlCtrl.rsptYrs.year6Date'] | limitTo: xmdlCtrl.colCount"><section col col-11>Year{{$index+1}}</section>

 <section col col-11>
   <label class="input"> <input id="year{{$index+1}}" 
          placeholder="MMM-YYYY" required="required" data-ng-model="'xmdlCtrl.rsptYrs.year{{$index+1}}Date" /</label></section></th>

 ........................
```

The above code when executed will create a token error since it will not allow `'{{}}'`

My actual requirement is that I want the ng-model to have the below name

`ng-model="xmdlCtrl.rsptYrs.year1Date"`
`ng-model="xmdlCtrl.rsptYrs.year2Date"`

and so on based on $index value from ng-repeat (this is literally equal to `xmdlCtrl.rsptYrs.year($index+1)Date`

I have gone through similar posts but none of them seem to have an accurate solution for the same.

Comment: Try this: `data-ng-model="xmdlCtrl.rsptYrs['year' + ($index+1) + 'Date']"`

Comment: @SlavaUtesinov Thankyou for your reply but this is causing : [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token '[' is not a valid identifier at.. error

Comment: eccentricCoder, it is working, as you can see at my answer. I assume you use too old AngularJS version.

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/8icp7tKi2d5zumJcgHhF?p=preview, please see if it helps

Comment: @SlavaUtesinov Harpreet Both your solutions are working perfectly. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
angular.module('app', []).controller('ctrl', function($scope){
  $scope.items = [{test1: 1}, {test2: 1}]
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app='app' ng-controller='ctrl'>
  <input ng-repeat-start='item in items' ng-model="item['test' + ($index + 1)]" type='number'/>  
  <br ng-repeat-end>
  {{items | json}}
</div>
```

Comment: @eccentricCoder, you should create plunker to reproduce your problem.

Comment: Thankyou so much. You saved my day. The code is working perfectly without any problem. It seemed to have been some cache issue. (I still don't know why it was not working before) I am deleting my previous comments where I stated it was not working because it should have worked then. Thanks a lot.

Comment: If you don't mind can you please explain how this is working (I did not clearly understand how it works) because as I have mentioned my ng-model name was `xmdlCtrl.rsptYrs.year2Date` and the model name that worked was data-ng-model="xmdlCtrl.rsptYrs['year' + ($index+1) + 'Date']"  which is missing the '. ' operator

Comment: @eccentricCoder, you simply used `rsptYrs.year{{$index+1}}Date` instead of `rsptYrs['year' + ($index+1) + 'Date']`. `{{}}` can't be used that way - in middle of name's property.